# Using NSolve after ParametricNDSolve to find the value of one parameter over a range of values of the other parameter and at a specific time

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, parameters, table

I am new to Mathematica, so excuse me if this is trivial. I could not find anything similar by browsing questions or the wiki.

I am working with a long set of ODEs but currently my problem can be watered down with the following example:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{f'[t] == (a+b)*f[t], f[0] == 1}, f, {t, 0, 10}, {a,b}]

Table[NSolve[Evaluate[{f[b][a][5]==0}/.sol],a],{b,2,4,0.5}]
```

What I am trying to accomplish with this is to calculate the value of `a` that yields `f[b][a][5]==0` for every `b` in the range `{b,2,4,0.5}`. However, I am getting the following error:

```
ParametricNDSolve::fpct: Too many parameters in {a,b} to be filled from {2}.
```

Thanks for taking the time to read, any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: As @Daniel Huber noticed I had the syntax for the two-parametric function wrong. With the corrected syntax,:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{f'[t] == (a+b)*f[t], f[0] == 1}, f, {t, 0, 10}, {a,b}]
    
    Table[NSolve[Evaluate[{f[b,a][5]==0}/.sol],a],{b,2,4,0.5}]
```

I no longer get the aforementioned error. Yet the output is blank `{{}, {}, {}, {}, {}}`.

Comment: The 2 parametric  function f needs 2 arguments, e.g. like f[2,1] and not f[2][1]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. When I modify the code to `f[b,a]` I no longer get the error. However, I don't get any results either. Instead, the output is `{{}, {}, {}, {}, {}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would play around with the function that you get *first* before trying to just use numerical root finding on the function.  For instance, a little playing around got me this:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{f'[t] == (a + b)*f[t], f[0] == 1}, f, {t, 0, 10}, {a, b}];
ContourPlot[0 == f[b, a][5] /. sol // Evaluate, {a, -12, -10}, {b, 2, 4}]
```

[image]

From there, we can use `FindRoot` along with some reasonable guesses for the value of `a` based on the intersection of those grid lines with the zero-contours of the function:

```
guesses = {-10.25, -11.75, -11.25, -12.75, -13, 25};
bs = Range[2, 4, 0.5];
Table[FindRoot[f[bs[[kk]], a][5] /. sol, {a, guesses[[kk]]}], {kk, 1, Length@bs}]
(* {{a -> -12.5729}, {a -> -15.1251}, {a -> -13.5729}, {a -> -16.1251}, {a -> -13.8383}} *)
```

Not perfect, but if give you the idea.

Comment: This worked, but unfortunately my system of DEs showed a very strange behavior with ParametricNDSolve with two parameters. I will probably post a more complete question with my full code. Thanks for taking the time to help!