# ParametricNDSolve with 2 parameters displays unexpected behavior, crosschecked with 1-parametric version of the same system

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions, singularity, parameters

I apologize in advance for posting some lengthy code, I tried to tackle this with a simplified question yesterday [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275870/using-nsolve-after-parametricndsolve-to-find-the-value-of-one-parameter-over-a-r) but once I implemented the suggested answer by @march deeper issues arose.

I am solving a complicated system of DEs with two parameters, `a` and `Nv1`. My goal is to solve for the values of `a` at a time `t=0.5` that yield `r[Nv1,a][0.5]==0` (`r[t]` is a variable of the DEs) over a range of values of `Nv1`. To put it simply, for every value of `Nv1` I need the value of `a` that sets `r[Nv1,a][0.5]==0`.

The following block of code constitutes my full model and system of equations. I will then provide my attempt at a solution along with comments about the problematic behavior of the solution.

```
L = 320;
B = 58;
d = 20.8;
Vol = 312600;
xG = 11.2;
Cb = 0.810;
HR = 15.80;
AR = 112.5;
Dp = 9.86;
SW = 27194;
radGyr = 0.25*L;
Uo = 2.5*0.514;
dens = 1023.6;
m = dens*Vol;
xR = -0.5*L;
IzG = m*radGyr^2;
eeta = Dp/HR;
tP = 0.220;
tR = 0.387;
aH = 0.312;
xH1 = -0.464;
xH = xH1*L;
C1 = 2;
lR1 = -0.710;
epsilon = 1.09;
kappa = 0.50;
fa = 2.747;
ko = 0.2931;
k1 = -0.2753;
k2 =-0.1385;
wpo = 0.35;
xp1 = -0.45;

(*non-dimensional*)
Xu1 = -0.00319
Xdu1 = -0.00114
Yv1 = -0.019
Ydv1 = -0.0145
Yr1 = 0.00572
Ydr1 = -0.00121
Nv1o = 0.00789
Ndv1 = -0.000588
Nr1 = -0.0037
Ndr1 = -0.000564

(*dimensionalization*)
Xu[t_]:= Xu1*0.5*dens*L^2*U[t]
Xdu = Xdu1*0.5*dens*L^3
Yv[t_]:= Yv1*0.5*dens*L^2*U[t]
Yr[t_]:= Yr1*0.5*dens*L^3*U[t]
Ydv = Ydv1*0.5*dens*L^3
Ydr = Ydr1*0.5*dens*L^4
Nv[t_]:= Nv1*0.5*dens*L^3*U[t]
Nr[t_]:= Nr1*0.5*dens*L^4*U[t]
Ndv = Ndv1*0.5*dens*L^4
Ndr = Ndr1*0.5*dens*L^5

U[t_]:=Sqrt[(v[t])^2+(u[t])^2]
beta[t_]:=ArcTan[-v[t]/u[t]]
v1[t_]:=v[t]/U[t]
u1[t_]:=u[t]/U[t]
r1[t_]:=r[t]*L/U[t]
np = -1.2755162450005562+1.7155853394588245*Uo-0.34572041553947347*Uo^2+0.03005809748872376*Uo^3;

XH[t_]:= Xu[t]*(u[t]-Uo)+Xdu*u'[t]
YH[t_]:= Ydv*v'[t]+Yv[t]*v[t]+Ydr*r'[t]+Yr[t]*r[t]
NH[t_]:= Ndv*v'[t]+Nv[t]*v[t]+Ndr*r'[t]+Nr[t]*r[t]

delta = 0;

XR[t_]:=-(1-tR)*FN[t]*Sin[delta];
YR[t_]:=-(1+aH)*FN[t]*Cos[delta];
NR[t_]:=-(xR+aH*xH)*FN[t]*Cos[delta];

FN[t_]:=(1/2)*dens*AR*(UR[t])^2*fa*Sin[aR[t]];

UR[t_]:=Sqrt[(vR[t])^2+(uR[t])^2];
aR[t_]:=delta-vR[t]/uR[t];

vR[t_]:=U[t]*gammaR[t]*betaR[t];
betaR[t_]:=beta[t]-lR1*r1[t];
gammaR[t_]:=Piecewise[{{0.395,betaR[t]<0},{0.640,betaR[t]>0}}];
(*gammaR[t_]:= 0.5;*)

uR[t_]:=epsilon*u[t]*(1-wp[t])*Sqrt[eeta*(1+kappa*(Sqrt[1+8*KT[t]/(Pi*(JP[t])^2)]-1)^2+(1-eeta))];
KT[t_]:=k2*(JP[t])^2+k1*JP[t]+ko;
JP[t_]:=u[t]*(1-wp[t])/(Dp*np);
betaP[t_]:=beta[t]-xp1*r1[t];
C2[t_]:=Piecewise[{{1.6,betaP[t]>0},{1.1,betaP[t]<0}}]
(*C2[t_]:=1;*)
wp[t_]:=-(1-wpo)*(1-Exp[-C1*Abs[betaP[t]]]*(C2[t]-1))+wpo;

XP[t_]:= (1- tP)*T[t];
T[t_]:= dens*np^2*Dp^4*KT[t];

CT = 4.1*10^(-3);
Res[t_]:= 0.5*dens*CT*SW*(U[t])^2;

F = 500;

X[t_]:=XH[t]+XR[t]+XP[t]-Res[t];
Y[t_]:=YH[t]+YR[t]+F;
Nm[t_]:=NH[t]+NR[t]+a*F; 

surge = m*(u'[t]-r[t]*v[t]-xG*(r[t])^2)==X[t];
sway = m*(v'[t]+r[t]*u[t]+xG*r'[t])==Y[t];
yaw = IzG*r'[t]+m*xG*(v'[t]+r[t]*u[t])==Nm[t];
```

**Attempt at a solution**

Based on the solution suggested in my previous post, I used the following lines of code

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{surge, sway, yaw, psi'[t]==r[t], u[0]==Uo, v[0]==0, r[0]==0, psi[0]==0},{u,v,r, psi},{t,0,200},{a,Nv1}, Method-> "DiscontinuityProcessing"-> False];
ContourPlot[0==r[Nv1,a][0.5]/.sol // Evaluate, {a,-L/2,L/2},{Nv1,0.0075,0.0090}]
```

This resulted in the following error

```
ParametricNDSolve::ndsz: At t == 0.8363529687932817`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.
```

and this contour plot

[image]

This error does not arise if the interval of `a` is constrained to `{a,0,L/2}`.

The contour plot shows no dependence of the value of `a` that sets `r[Nv1,a][t]==0` on `Nv1`. Besides the fact, that this behavior is unnatural, we can crosscheck by scaling down the problem to a single-parametric set of DEs and manually changing the other parameter. For instance, setting `Nv1 = 0.00789` and keeping `a` as the single parameter as shown below

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{surge, sway, yaw, psi'[t]==r[t], u[0]==Uo, v[0]==0, r[0]==0, psi[0]==0},{u,v,r, psi},{t,0,200},{a},Method-> "DiscontinuityProcessing"-> False]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[r[a][t]/.sol,{a, -L/2, L/2, 32}]],{t,0,3},PlotRange->All,PlotLegends->LineLegend[Table[a,{a,-L/2,L/2,32}],LegendLabel->a],AxesLabel->{"t","r(t)"}, PlotLabel->"Yaw angular velocity for different moment levers a"]

LCR0 = FindRoot[r[a][0.5]/.sol,{a,11}]
```

presents no issues with negative values of `a` and the output is `{a -> 11.8694}`. Manually, setting `Nv1=0.009`, for example, has an output of `{a -> 11.8584}` for the `FindRoot` argument. In my understanding, this goes to show, that in reality

1. The value of `a` that sets `r[Nv1,a][t]==0` is different than that displayed on the `ContourPlot` of the two-parametric system of DE and that it should depend on `Nv1` contrary to what the plot suggests, where it appears constant.
2. There should not be any issues with negative values of `a`.

Thanks for taking the time to read through. I would appreciate some help with tackling this or getting around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, someone is interested in the future, this is a workaround based on suggestions from another source:

```
func[c_?NumericQ,a_?NumericQ]:= Module[{sol},
                sol = NDSolve[{
                    m*(u'[t]-r[t]*v[t]-xG*(r[t])^2)==X[t], (*surge*)
                    m*(v'[t]+r[t]*u[t]+xG*r'[t])==Y[t], (*sway*)
                    (IzG+m*xG^2)*r'[t]+m*xG*(v'[t]+r[t]*u[t])==Nm[t,c,a], (*yaw*)
                    (*initial conditions*)
                    u[0]==Uo, v[0]==0, r[0]==0},
                    {u,v,r},{t,0,200},Method-> "DiscontinuityProcessing"-> False];
                r[0.5]/.sol];

cs = Range[0.7, 1.3, 0.05];

Table[FindRoot[func[cs[[kk]],a],{a,12}],{kk,1, Length@cs}]
```

It also involves a slight correction in the system that was used but this is mostly irrelevant to the solution of the problem (just a constant term missing). I have not yet understood why `ParametricNDSolve` displayed the behavior described in the original question but this, at least for my needs, "solved" the issue.

*Notes*

- `c` is used to change the values of `Nv1` in the original question by multiplying `Nv1o`
- `x_?NumericQ` notation is used for `c` and `a` throughout the entire code.
- Lines of code involving `c` and `a` are changed accordingly, i.e. `Nm[t_,c_?NumericQ,a_?NumericQ]:=NH[t,c]+NR[t]+a*F;`